# How to get both present and absent students for a year

Tags: mysql

I need to get the total no. present and absent students in a year from a table attendance:
Here is my query:

```
SELECT if( status = 'P',count(level_id), 0) AS present, 
       if(status='A',count(student_id), 0) AS Absent 
        FROM attendance WHERE level_id = 'L1' AND date LIKE '2016%'
```

But this returns the total no. of students to either present or absent section.

Comment: Please format your sql query for better understanding

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you misunderstood what `COUNT(...)` does in the query. If you really want to count based on being absent or present, then you can use `SUM(...)` with a conditional step inside.

```
SELECT
    SUM(if(status = 'P', 1, 0)) AS Present
    SUM(if(status = 'A', 1, 0)) AS Absent
FROM
    attendance
WHERE
    level_id = 'L1' AND date LIKE '2016%'
```

Comment: I agree with that answer. but make sure that the student appears only once in the table. Else you will not count the number of present students, but the sum of the occurences of each present student. wich might be wrong for your needs (i do not know).
If you need to count students, then a group by may be needed.

Answer (score 1):

Return 1 if you need to count th element:

```
 SELECT SUM(if( status = 'P',1, 0)) AS present, SUM(if(status='A',1, 0)) AS Absent
 FROM attendance WHERE level_id = 'L1' AND date LIKE '2016%'
```

Answer (score 0):

Try **group by** clause like:

```
SELECT 
 status, 
 count(student_id) as attendance 
FROM attendance 
WHERE level_id = 'L1' 
  AND date LIKE '2016%' 
GROUP BY status;
```

It will give you the count for each status available in table

Answer (score 0):

This will work:

```
SELECT DISTINCT(student_name), SUM(status = 'P') AS present, SUM(status='A') AS Absent FROM attendance GROUP BY student_name where date LIKE '2016%'
```